# Why can't I access variables through the DS segment register?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, dos, masm

I wrote the following real-mode 8086 assembly program that's supposed to fill the whole screen with asterisks but it's not working properly - it seems that the `position` variable cannot be accessed from the `callback` function. What's weird for me is that it works if I move all the variables from the `data` section to the `code` section. What am I doing wrong here?

```asm
.386
ASSUME ds:data, cs:code, ss:stack

VEC8_OFFSET  = 8 * 4
VRAM_SEGMENT = 0B8000h / 010h
VRAM_SIZE    = 4000
IVT_BEGIN    = 0

data SEGMENT
    position     dw 0
    default_vec8 dd (?)
data ENDS

code SEGMENT use16 para public 'code'
callback PROC
    push fs
    push bx

    mov bx, VRAM_SEGMENT
    mov fs, bx

    mov bx, ds:position

    mov BYTE PTR fs:[bx], '*'
    mov BYTE PTR fs:[bx+1], 11100001b

    add bx, 2
    if_overflow:
        cmp bx, VRAM_SIZE
        jne end_if1
        mov bx, 0
    end_if1:
    mov ds:position, bx

    pop bx
    pop fs

    jmp DWORD PTR ds:default_vec8
callback ENDP

main PROC
; Initialize text mode
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 5
    int 10

; ES: Interrupt Vector Table segment
    mov ax, IVT_BEGIN
    mov es, ax

; Saving the 8th vector
    mov eax, es:[VEC8_OFFSET]
    mov ds:default_vec8, eax

; Installing the callback function
    mov ax, SEG callback
    mov bx, OFFSET callback
    cli
    mov es:[VEC8_OFFSET], bx
    mov es:[VEC8_OFFSET + 2], ax
    sti

; Await input
    await:
        if_key_pressed:
            mov ah, 1
            int 16h
            jz end_if2
        if_pressed_x:
            mov ah, 0
            int 16h
            cmp al, 'x'
            je end_await
        end_if2:
        
        jmp await
    end_await:

    mov eax, ds:default_vec8
    cli
    mov es:[VEC8_OFFSET], eax
    sti

; Exit the program
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
main ENDP

code ENDS

stack SEGMENT stack
    db 128 dup (?)
stack ENDS

END main
```

Comment: You did not even initialize `ds`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, I thought that's what the `ASSUME` directive was used for. Can you tell me how can I get the address of a segment in MASM? I've added
`mov ax, data`, `mov ds, ax`
to the `main` function and it works, but I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it.

Comment: `assume` directives do not emit any code, they're only for you to tell the assembler what you think the segment registers point to, so that it can access variables with the right segregs.

Comment: @SaJmoN Instead of guessing what directives do, consider reading the manual of the assembler you are programming for.

Comment: @SaJmoN Yes, that's how it's done.